# Stop excel from converting number values to date when exporting

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have an application that when I click Run Report button, it will generate data and will be exported to excel.

My problem is that, I have a data in a column which is Requisition No. and the value of this column is for example is like this `08-20` but when I export it on excel it will became a date `20-Aug`

[image: Excel]

Please understand that I already searched for a solution. I saw one similar to my problem but I don't have a gridview, when I click the Run Report it will automatically generate data and then export.

**EDIT**

Here's my code for `fnGeneratereport` in `DAL`

```
  Public Shared Function FnGenerateReport(ByVal rm As ReportModel) As DataTable
        Dim dtbReport As New DataTable
        Dim strQuery As New StringBuilder

        strQuery.Append("SELECT R.iResumeID, R.vFirst, R.vMiddle, R.vLast, J.vGeneric, JC.vJobClass, R.dtApply, R.iChannelID, ")
        strQuery.Append("HS.vHireStatus, R.dtHire, R.vGender, R.vRace, R.vEthnicity, R.vDisability, R.vVeteran, R.vRemarks AS Remarks, J.ftAdCost,R.iTimeToHire AS iTimeToHire, ")
        strQuery.Append("D.vDivision AS iDivisionID, J.vLocation AS vLocation, J.vLocalised as vLocalised, R.blnEmployee AS blnEmployee, ")
        strQuery.Append("S.vFullName as vFullName, R.vComments as Comments, JT.vJobCodeTitle as JobCodeTitle, ")
        strQuery.Append("J.iPosition as PositionType, J.iJobStatus as JobStatus, J.dtPost as DateJobPosted, R.dtAccepted as JobOfferAcceptedDate, ")
        strQuery.Append("HC.vHCClassificationTitle as ClassificationTitle, J.iHourlySalariedID as HourlySalaried J.vRequisition as vRequisition")
        strQuery.Append("FROM VS_ResumeDB R ")
        strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN VS_JobDB J ON R.iJobID = J.iJobID ")
        strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN VS_CountryDB C ON J.iCountryID = C.iCountryID ")
        strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN VS_DivisionDB D ON (J.iDivisionID = D.iDivisionID) ")
        strQuery.Append("LEFT JOIN VS_StaffDB S ON J.iRecruiterID = S.iStaffID ")
        strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN VS_HireStatusDB HS ON R.iHireStatusID = HS.iHireStatusID ")
        strQuery.Append("LEFT JOIN VS_JobClassDB JC ON J.iJobClassID = JC.iJobClassID ")
        strQuery.Append("LEFT JOIN VS_JobCodeTitleDB JT ON JT.iJobCodeID = J.iJobCodeID ")
        strQuery.Append("LEFT JOIN VS_HCClassificationDB HC on HC.iHCClassificationID = J.iHCClassificationID ")
        strQuery.Append("WHERE R.blnComplete=1 ")

        If Len(rm.intCountry) > 0 And rm.intCountry <> 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.iCountryID=@CountryID ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.intDivisionID) > 0 And rm.intDivisionID <> 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.iDivisionID=@DivisionID ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.strLocation) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.vLocation LIKE @Location ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.dtePostFrom) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND R.dtApply>=@PostFrom ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.dtePostTo) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND R.dtApply<=@PostTo ")
            strQuery.Append("AND J.dtPost<=@PostTo ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.strRequisition) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.vRequisition LIKE @Requisition ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.intHireStatus) > 0 And rm.intHireStatus <> 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND R.iHireStatusID=@HireStatus ")
        End If
        If rm.intType = 0 Or rm.intType = 1 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND R.blnEmployee=@Type ")
        End If
        If rm.intJobStatus <> 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.iJobStatus=@JobStatus ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.dteJobPostFrom) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.dtPost>=@JobPostFrom ")
        End If
        If Len(rm.dteJobPostTo) > 0 Then
            strQuery.Append("AND J.dtPost<=@JobPostTo ")
        End If

        Return dtbReport
    End Function
```

And here's my code when I click Run Report

```
Private Function FnGenerateReport() As String
    arrColumn(0) = 0
    arrColumn(1) = rm.intColumn1
    arrColumn(2) = rm.intColumn2
    arrColumn(3) = rm.intColumn3
    arrColumn(4) = rm.intColumn4
    arrColumn(5) = rm.intColumn5
    arrColumn(6) = rm.intColumn6
    arrColumn(7) = rm.intColumn7
    arrColumn(8) = rm.intColumn8
    arrColumn(9) = rm.intColumn9
    arrColumn(10) = rm.intColumn10
    arrColumn(11) = rm.intColumn11
    arrColumn(12) = rm.intColumn12
    arrColumn(13) = rm.intColumn13
    arrColumn(14) = rm.intColumn14
    arrColumn(15) = rm.intColumn15
    arrColumn(16) = rm.intColumn16
    arrColumn(17) = rm.intColumn17
    arrColumn(18) = rm.intColumn18
    arrColumn(19) = rm.intColumn19
    arrColumn(20) = rm.intColumn20
    arrColumn(21) = rm.intColumn21
    arrColumn(22) = rm.intColumn22
    arrColumn(23) = rm.intColumn23
    arrColumn(24) = rm.intColumn24
    arrColumn(25) = rm.intColumn25
    arrColumn(26) = rm.intColumn26
    arrColumn(27) = rm.intColumn27

    Dim strHTML As String = "<table border=""1""><tr>"

    Dim dtbReport As DataTable = BLL.FnGenerateReport(rm)
    For intColCount As Int16 = 1 To 27
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 1 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Applicant Name</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 2 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Job Applied for</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 3 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>EEO-1 Job Classification</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 4 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Date Applied</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 5 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Gender</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 6 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Race</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 7 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Source of Application</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 8 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Status of Application</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 9 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Date of Hire</strong></td><"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 10 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Remarks</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 11 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Advertising Cost</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 12 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Time to Hire</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 13 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Division</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 14 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Location</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 15 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Job Title(Localised)</strong> </td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 16 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Internal or External</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 17 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Recruiter</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 18 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Comments</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 19 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Job Code/Title</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 20 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Position Type</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 21 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Job Status</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 22 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Date Job Posted</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 23 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Job offer accepted Date</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 24 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>HC Classification</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 25 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Hourly/Salaried</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 26 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Ethnicity</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 27 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Disability Status</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 28 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Veteran Status</strong></td>"
        End If
        If arrColumn(intColCount) = 29 Then
            strHTML += "<td><strong>Requisition No.</strong></td>"
        End If
    Next
    strHTML += "</tr>"

    If dtbReport.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dtbReport.Rows
            strHTML += "<tr/>"
            For intColCount2 As Int16 = 1 To 27
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 1 Then
                    strHTML += "<td><a href=" & strMainFolderName & "Resume_Details.aspx?r=" & dr("iResumeID") & ">" & dr("vFirst") & " " & dr("vMiddle") & " " & dr("vLast") & "</a></td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 2 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vGeneric") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 3 Then
                    strHTML += "<td nowrap>" & dr("vJobClass") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 4 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("dtApply").ToShortDateString & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 5 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vGender") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 6 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vRace") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 7 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr("iChannelID")) Then
                        Dim strChannel As String = BLL.FnGetChannel(CInt(dr("iChannelID")))
                        strHTML += strChannel
                    End If
                    strHTML += "&nbsp;</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 8 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vHireStatus") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 9 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If IsDate(dr("dtHire")) Then
                        strHTML += dr("dtHire").ToShortDateString
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 10 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("Remarks") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 11 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr("ftAdCost")) Then
                        Replace(FormatNumber(dr("ftAdCost"), 2), ",", "")
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 12 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("iTimeToHire") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 13 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("iDivisionID") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 14 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vLocation") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 15 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vLocalised") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 16 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If (dr("blnEmployee")) = "True" Then
                        strHTML += "Internal"
                    Else
                        strHTML += "External"
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 17 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vFullName") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 18 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("Comments") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 19 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("JobCodeTitle") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 20 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If (dr("PositionType")) = 1 Then
                        strHTML += "Full-Time"
                    ElseIf (dr("PositionType")) = 2 Then
                        strHTML += "Part-Time"
                    ElseIf (dr("PositionType")) = 3 Then
                        strHTML += "Internship"
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 21 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If dr("JobStatus") = 1 Then
                        strHTML += "Draft"
                    ElseIf dr("JobStatus") = 2 Then
                        strHTML += "Posted"
                    ElseIf dr("JobStatus") = 3 Then
                        strHTML += "Closed"
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 22 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If IsDate(dr("DateJobPosted")) Then
                        strHTML += dr("DateJobPosted").ToShortDateString
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 23 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If IsDate(dr("JobOfferAcceptedDate")) Then
                        strHTML += dr("JobOfferAcceptedDate").ToShortDateString
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 24 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("ClassificationTitle") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 25 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>"
                    If dr("HourlySalaried") = 1 Then
                        strHTML += "Hourly"
                    ElseIf dr("HourlySalaried") = 2 Then
                        strHTML += "Salaried"
                    End If
                    strHTML += "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 26 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vEthnicity") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 27 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vDisability") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 28 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vVeteran") & "</td>"
                End If
                If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 29 Then
                    strHTML += "<td>" & dr("vRequisition") & "</td>"
                End If
            Next
            strHTML += "</tr>"
        Next
    End If
    strHTML += "</table>"
    Return strHTML
End Function
```

Comment: What are you using to export data to excel ?

Comment: Try prepending an apostrophe (single quote) to the Requisition No.

Comment: @MrGadget where do I put single quote?

Comment: Now that I see you're dealing with HTML formatted content, I guess you're just trying to copy & paste this output into Excel. Excel needs to know that value is to be treated as text. This may not help your situation but the change would be `strHTML += "<td>&apos;" & dr("vRequisition") & "</td>"` -- see where I put the `&apos;` in there.

Comment: Prepend means 'insert at the start'

Comment: If you're doing copy & paste, does Excel give you the opportunity to select the columns and choose the data type? I haven't used Excel in years so I can't recall.

Comment: actually I'm new with this exporting data into excel, someone was actually the first who did this application but unfortunately he's not here anymore. So when I click the run report the data will be exported to excel are you asking if I can select it as Number, Short Date, Text etc.? if yes then I can select the column and choose the data type when I open the excel.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. You'll lose the datatype because all you are exporting are strings.

Comment: @chobowski To amplify what others have written, the ONLY way you will be able to get Excel to not transform a string that looks like a date is to ensure Excel sees that string as TEXT at the time it is written to the cell.  Two ways to do this are to designate the column as TEXT **before** you write the data (i.e. change your import to excel routine), or prepend the data with a single quote (which will NOT appear in the cell, but will appear in the formula bar).

Comment: Okay I'm sorry for a late reply. I put strHTML += "<td>&apos;" & dr("vRequisition") & "</td>" but now even the &apos; is visible in the excel.

Comment: is it possible to hide the ' (single quote) in the excel?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the setting of the column forehand, to either text or numbers?
if you mark the whole column you can, in the start toolbar change the format of the column. you can choose in a dropdown menu from standard, date, test etc.

Comment: yes I tried. But every time I export another data, it's still the same.